# reCaptcha redirecting to a 404

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the login URL supplied by `UserService.createLoginURL(...)` as described in http://gae-login-explainer.appspot.com/#section_GAE_login.

The problem is that when one of my users encounters a reCaptcha, upon completion they are redirected to https://accounts.google.com/signin/lookup instead of back to my site.

The redirected link `https://accounts.google.com/signin/lookup` is a 404 page.

The relevant code in question is:

```
<?php

use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;

$url = UserService::createLoginURL($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

`$url` is `https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/conflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps://*****.appspot.com/`.

Is anyone else seeing the same thing? Is there anything I can try to change?

Comment: I've found that if a user logs out of Google, and then tries to log into my site - it works. I'm not sure in what causes Google to force users to enter a captcha, but when it does happen they are thrown into a 404.